# Add newly installed programs to Start in Windows 8.1

Tags: start-screen, windows-8.1

In Windows 8, when I installed a program it automatically shows up in Start.

But in Windows 8.1, this behaviour is missing. Every time I installed a new program I have to search for it and manually click on "Pin to Start"

Is there a way to get the old Windows 8 behaviour back?

Comment: For me this is one of the most significant IMPROVEMENT of 8.1. I hated that the start screen is floated with a lot of crap.

Answer (score 0):

In windows view (displayed when Window key is pressed), there is a downward pointing arrow at the bottom. ON clicking, it shows all the installed applications. IMO, it is done to remove clutter from windows screen and infinite scrolling.